# Mysql: How get max id along with other fields from three tables that have reference

Tags: mysql

I Have three table A, B, C. A have reference key from B and C. I need to get max id along with user name and department name in the result.

Table user:

| id | user_id | departmen_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 12 |
| 2 | 22 | 13 |
| 3 | 22 | 14 |

Table user:

| id | userName | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | robert | rob@email |

Table depart:

| id | department |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | dev |
| 13 | tech |
| 14 | support |

My query:

```
select max(c.id), c.user_id, u.userName, d.department from connections c 
INNER JOIN user u ON c.user_id = u.id 
INNER JOIN depart d ON c.departmen_id = d.id GROUP BY c.user_id
```

Result I am getting now

| id | userName | department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | robert | dev |

Expected result

| id | userName | department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | robert | support |

Any suggestions?

Comment: where is your `connections` table?

Comment: Hello @Asgar, Sorry my bad, the first table is connections table which having id, user_id, departmen_id fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a subquery to get the max id from connections table grouped by userid

try this:

```
SELECT 
  c.`id`,
  c.`user_id`,
  u.`userName`,
  d.`department` 
FROM
  connections c 
  JOIN `user` u ON c.user_id = u.id 
  JOIN depart d ON c.departmen_id = d.id 
WHERE c.`id` = 
  (SELECT  MAX(c1.`id`) maxId 
  FROM
    connections c1 
  WHERE c1.`user_id` = c.`user_id`)
```

Let me know if it works or what goes wrong

Comment: Thanks Asgar for the reply. I am getting partial result . Example I have 1000 records in connections and it should return more than 600 rows but now I am getting only 200 records.

Comment: ```SELECT 
  c.`id`,
  c.`user_id`,
  u.`userName`,
  d.`department` 
FROM
  connections c 
  JOIN `user` u ON c.user_id = u.id 
  JOIN depart d ON c.departmen_id = d.id 
WHERE c.`id` = 
  (SELECT  MAX(c1.`id`) maxId 
  FROM
    connections c1 
  WHERE c1.`id` = c.`id`)``` 

With this I am getting expected rows with invalid department name.

Comment: Cannot tell more without having some sample and twisting data to check